# Insert in empty cells values from the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to seach in an column if there are similar id's and if yes ro copy the group and insert in the empty cell.

I have the following table

```
Group  Status  ID
       Log in   1
       Log out  1
       Log in   3
       Log out  2
A               1
B               2
C               3
```

The table should look like this:

```
Group  Status  ID
A      Log in   1
A      Log out  1
C      Log in   3
B      Log out  2
A               1
B               2
C               3
```

To do this I tried to use this formula:

```
=IF(C2=(C4:C7);(A4:A7);IF(C2=(C4:C7);(A4:A7);""))
```

Unfortunatly it is not working, any idea why?

Comment: What is `C4:C7` evaluate to? Should this be the sum? Count?

Comment: Do your groups correspond to IDs? I.E. `A = 1`, `B = 2`, `C = 3` etc...?

Comment: The range. From C4 to C7. I want to check if C2 is equal with a value from this range

Comment: Yes, the groups correspound to ID's, but i need to find them and insert in the empy cells

Comment: Why not just use a `VLOOKUP` on `Column A`?

Comment: Yes VLOOKUP, but how can I insert them in my function or I need to create another function?

Comment: I would just not use your function and take a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a table that matches your IDs to Groups (table on right). This can be housed on a hidden sheet and updated in future as needed (which will be much easier to manage in comparison to updating tedious nested `IF` statements formulas)
2. Insert `VLOOKUP` on your main table
3. Drag formula down to end of range

*In the formula, `Table1` is the name of the right table that houses your matching Groups*

---

*result*

[image]

*formulas used*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I get what you mean, but I'd try something like this

```
=INDEX($C$6:$C$8,MATCH(E2,$E$6:$E$8,0),1)
```

Comment: Something like this. Thanks for the idea.